# Is there any fast way to calculate the folder size under LNUX/UNIX

Tags: bash

I got a lot of folders, each folder is around 150GB. Yes, the whole storage is very large. I use the Linux command line:

```
for dir in `ls myfolder`
do
    du -sh $dir >> statistics.log
done
```

Very slow, it has been running for 3 days. Is there any fast way to do this?? Thanks a lot

Comment: `du -sh folder` should take less than a second to return the size of folders below 500GB but it also depends on how many files and sub folders inside each folder. What is the total count of files and sub folders per folder?

Comment: I don't think that script will even work. `ls myfolder` just returns filenames. It will then look for those filenames in the current directory, not under `myfolder`.

Comment: It should never take so long. A few minutes at most I would think. Maybe it's time to run `fsck`?

Comment: By the way, it's not really relevant how much data is in the folder. The question is how many files. If you have one 150GB file, `du` will compute its size instantly. If you have a million one-byte files, expect it to take a while to add them up to a million bytes.

Comment: @rici particularly with spinning platters, parallel will likely kill you on seek times, depending on how the file system is laid out.  The networked case might be the only one where it might help, but as you say, run the job on the file server.

Comment: @NathanKidd: I meant that advice to apply only to network file systems. An NFS with various TB probably has the capacity to do more than one seek at a time.

Comment: (Updated comment) Is that folder on a network file system? That would certainly slow down du. In that case, the answer would be to do it on the fileserver, if at all possible. If you can't get at the fileserver, you can probably speed things up by running a number of `du`'s in parallel.

Comment: @Barmar it works. You should have a try yourself.

Comment: I just tried it -- I get lots of "du: _filename_: No such file or directory" errors. Does your current directory happen to have lots of subdirs with the same names as in `myfolder`? Another problem with your script is it doesn't work if any files/directories in `myfolder` have spaces in their names.

Comment: @Barmar, ha, I just simplify the code to let people understand my code structure easily. In your case, Remember to put the full path: du -sh fullpathfolder

Comment: If you just wrote `du -sh myfolder/$dir` there would have been no confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just do `du -sh /path/*` also you could read about `updatedb` which might be updating your index in the background, once this is complete, you might experience a performance gain with `du`

Comment: I tried your method, it still needs a really long time to run, Possibly I have to use multithreading to do this..

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a for loop. The du command accepts a path, so give it the desired path and don't use a loop. For example see: [calc folder size](https://superuser.com/questions/162749/how-to-get-the-summarized-sizes-of-folders-and-their-subfolders).

Comment: why not use a loop here? Thx!

Comment: The du command will do the loop for you assuming your folders are all the nodes in a given tree path. If you have specific list of paths that are disjoint, say in two separate disks and you want to du bot, then you could use a loop. Check the link for an example.

Comment: Thanks~ But I do need the loop in my case. I was thinking to use the multithreading to accelerate the progress.